# fast filtering of sentences in spacy

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, transformer-model, sentence

I'm using SpaCy to divide a text into sentences, match a regex pattern on each sentence, and use some logic based on the results of the match. I started with a naive approach such as:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
regex = re.compile(r'\b(foo|bar)\b')

for text in texts_list:
  doc = nlp(text)
  for sent in doc.sents:
    if re.search(regex, str(s)):
    [...]
    else:
    [...]
```

and it was very slow. Then I used a pipe:

```
for doc in nlp.pipe(texts_list, disable=['tagger', 'ner', 'attribute_ruler', 'lemmatizer'], n_process=4):
  for sent in doc.sents:
    if re.search(regex, str(s)):
    [...]
    else:
    [...]
```

but it's still slow. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A transformer model is overkill for splitting sentences and will be very slow. Instead, a good option is the fast `senter` from an `sm` model:

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm", disable=["tok2vec", "tagger", "parser", "attribute_ruler", "lemmatizer", "ner"])
nlp.enable_pipe("senter")
for doc in nlp.pipe(texts, n_process=4):
    ...
```

The `senter` should work pretty well if your sentences end with punctuation. If you have a lot of run-on sentences without final punctuation, then the `parser` might do a better job. To run only the parser, keep the `tok2vec` and `parser` components from the original pipeline and don't enable the `senter`. The `parser` will be ~5-10x slower than the `senter`.

If you need this to be even faster, you can use the rule-based `sentencizer` (start from a blank `en` model), which is typically a bit worse than the `senter` because it only splits on the provided punctuation symbols.

Comment: Thanks, I need the sub-word tokenization and the parser for other parts of the code, but I wonder why switching to `pipe` and using multiple processes hasn't sped things up.

Comment: Would running the parser only on things that match the regex help you? You could use the small model for sentence tokenization and then apply the trf model after that as needed.

Comment: @polm23 Yeah, that's a great idea. Thanks!